# Encountered undefined provider! Usually this means you have cies. This might be caused by using 'barrel' index.ts files

Tags: angular, typescript

[this is the error which i get in production build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvbWN.png) [image]
[image]

by using Layout Module.ts file as child where all the inner pages are included and ,app module.ts as parent including only the app component.ts file ,whenever I use (ng build --prod)

it show :
/error message as/

circular dependencies (might be caused by using 'barrel' index.ts files.

Comment: you should share your code here, so that we can help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! Please post your code in the question itself, with any relevant output / error messages as *text* (not image or link), for various reasons, see : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/479251 . Also relevant : [mcve]

Comment: ya sure ill do tht

Answer (score 1):

I know it's hard to post the whole project because this issue more or less relates to the circular dependencies injection. This usually happens like, for example, you have 3 files `a.ts`, `b.ts`, `c.ts` and `a import b, b import c and c import a`. Or even more.

So my suggestion to debug this case is to check if your ts files to find out the circular loop.

Comment: or is there any other way other ,or if i use only the app.routing to add all the inner pages is tht a good practise

Comment: That is not the real problem I think, but you can try